# PHP: Store and/or pass reference to class

Tags: php, class, variables, storage, pass-by-reference

Given the following structure:

```
class B 
{
    private $_b;
    private __constructor() { }

    public function setValue( $value ) 
    {
        $this->_b->setValue( $value );
    }

    public static function load( &$__b ) 
    {
        $B = new B();
        $B->_b = $__b;
        return $B;
    }
}
class A 
{
    private $_b;

    public function getB() 
    {
        return B::load( $this->_b );
    }

    public function save() 
    {
        $this->_b->save();
    }
}
$_SESSION['a'] = new A();
```

The following does not work:

```
$b = $_SESSION['a']->getB();
$b->setValue( 'value' );
$_SESSION['a']->save();
```

However, the following does work:

```
$_SESSION['a']->getB()->setValue( 'value' );
$_SESSION['a']->save();
```

I know someone here will see what's wrong, or if it's not even possible.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Is your test considering the un/serialize process happening when sessions are opened / closed?

This should not ever work. `A::getB()` does not update its reference kept in `A::_b`. `B::load()` receives the data by reference, but does not referentially assign it to `$B->_b`. Assuming that `$__b` is an object itself, this will work in PHP5. Not because you passed it to the load() function by reference - but because objects are always handled referentially.

maybe you want to elaborate on your code example. Explaining how the the value `$_SESSION['a']` came to be would be a great start.

Comment: I added how `$_SESSION['a']` is created. This did work before and the reference works because it is created using a reference. The underlying `_b` is all that needs to be a reference, the class itself does not need to be.

Comment: Sorry, but `$a = new A(); $b = $a->getB(); $b->setValue("v");` will cause a Fatal Error `Called method on non-object`.

Answer (score 0):

This question was not needed, the code in the original post works exactly as it is intended (pass-by-reference), and allows for storing in a variable.

My issue was with modifying the `private $_b` incorrectly in the constructor which was forcing it not to be a reference.